# SQL Server 2008R2 DBCC CheckDB never finishing

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server, dbcc-checkdb

I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows server 2008 R2 and up until recently we were having no problems. After windows updates recently (no sql server updates) we cannot run step 1 of our maintenance plan DBCC CHECKDB It does not error out, it just runs indefinitely, longest time so far 36 hours. The DB is only about 500MB so I dont think size is an issue.

I was just wondering if anyone has seen this sort of issue in the past.

Edit:
For what it is worth I also noticed rebuilding index and updating statistics is having the same issue. I have no idea if this helps.

Edit2:
So if if it helps anyone after running SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests; I'm seeing the wait type CXPACKET on the following tasks: ALTER INDEX, DBCC;

Comment: what is the dbcc's request `status`, `wait_time`, `wait_type`, `last_wait_type` in [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx)

Comment: Status: suspended, wait_time: 28309911, wait_type: CXPACKET, last_wait_type: CXPACKET

Comment: This will help you http://www.sqlmag.com/blog/sql-server-questions-answered-28/database-administration/locking-dbcc-checkdb-143608 . BTW, can you backup the same database and restore it on some other test server and then run CHECKDB, to see if it times out or not ?

Comment: Not really, we dont have a suitable test server available. Although if it comes to it i guess it might be necessary

Comment: Also run "SELECT * from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks where session_id=DBCC_ID". Where DBCC_ID is the numeric session ID for the DBCC task. If CXPACKET is the issue try this article: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/13/sql-server-reducing-cxpacket-wait-stats-for-high-transactional-database/

Comment: looks like CXPACKET is the issue allright. blocking seesion id of the process is itself and wait_type is CXPACKET... This is just standard maintenance plan from the wizzard im surprised im running into this.

Comment: Hmmm, This is a production server so I'm slow to do any changes that effect the server wide parallel operation.

Comment: Paul Randal just [blogged](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/dbcc-checkdb-performance-and-computed-column-indexes) about CHECKDB running very slowly (by design) against databases that contain indexes on computed columns. Perhaps there was an application update? Try running the diagnostic query from the blog post. (If this is the problem, unfortunately there is no resolution, but at least it's an answer to the question.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a very interesting post on DBCC CHECKDB on SqlPerformance, [Minimize impact of checkdb](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/11/io-subsystem/minimize-impact-of-checkdb). This will give you several ideas, like testing your backup on another server (therefore offloading the charge), using several options (you can experiment with PHYSICAL_ONLY for example).

As CHECKDB is making a big use of tempdb, this you check how things are going on for this database? Is it on separate disk?

Comment: Yes, it is on a NAS connected over fast ethernet so we are never expecting it to run at blinding speed but 48 hours plus on 500MB database seems like something is definitly wrong. using Physical_Only and the problem remains the same

Comment: @Nick, do you have some funny DB parameters like autoshrink, or something else? Did you try to restore and test on another server? Could you also check this DB VLFs ?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary, DBCC is being called from maintenance plan but running it manually also times out.